# rendering without light only texture as they are

Tags: texturing, light

I am new to blender and I only want to take pictures of 3d model from the side. I have everthing set up. Camera is looking exactly from the side and set to orthographic.

But either I have a light which leads to surfaces being differently illuminated as they would in reality or I don't have a light and everything is black.

All what I want to have is the texture (jpeg) on my model as they are in the jpeg.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you:)

Comment: You could use the world lighting, basically a background illumination, which should lead to every surface being illuminated evenly. First delete every lamp in your scene, then go to world and adjust the horizen color. Alternatively you can upload your blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I can have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to do this. Here's my solution:

[image]

1. Hide all lights in your scene by selecting lights and pressing H.
2. Set your world to white. If there's no color selection, you may check "Use Nodes" to create nodes before you change the world color.

[image]

3. Use Node Wrangler. It's a built-in plug-in. Ctrl+Alt+U to call User Preferences. Go to Addons and search "Node Wrangler", and tick it, then save user settings.
4. Go to Node Editor, and build up your materials for the object. Once finished, you want to make a solo preview of your texture, so **press Ctrl+Shift+LMB on an image node** of your diffuse BSDF to make it solo in preview.

[image]
(The dotted line was the original line in final, but I make a solo preview of the texture, as you can see the Material Output receives input from a Viewer, followed with Image node.)

5. Render, or make a viewport render, by Shift+Z.

[image]

Alternatively, You can also make screenshots in Material viewport.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the effort. But I found out that it is enough to check "shadeless" under the material tab.

Comment: haha I should congratulate you on your effort to dig out a onekey solution!

Comment: @Peter I can't find the shadeless option, where is it?